# getting error while using base_uri() in href

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying this, but it does not work.

```
echo "<a  class='btn btn-info btn-md' href='<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Welcome/editvendor/$row->VendorId'>Edit</a>";
```

URI does not get loaded.

Comment: echo "<td> <a  class='btn btn-info btn-md' href='<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Welcome/editvendor/$row->VendorId'>Edit</a></td>";

Comment: in autoload.php add $autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
echo "<td><a class='btn btn-info btn-md' href='".base_url("/Welcome/editvendor/".$row->VendorId)."'>Edit</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<td> <a class='btn btn-info btn-md' href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Welcome/editvendor/'.$row->VendorId); ?>">Edit</a></td>
```

Comment: are u using your code in controller or view,..?? hve u set the base url in config..?? and added the url helper in autoload.php..?? please define all this in your question...

Comment: i am not added url helper in autoload.set url in config.i am use this code in view.thank you it work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Your `echo` statement should be

```
echo "<td> <a class='btn btn-info btn-md' href='". base_url() ."'index.php/Welcome/editvendor/'.$row->VendorId.'">Edit</a></td>";
```

Then in `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And in `config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you default controller is `welcome` (in /config/routes.php `$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";`), then your links should look like this when you use `base_url()`:

```
"<a class='whatever' href='". base_url() ."'editvendor/'".$row->VendorId."'>Edit</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<a class='btn btn-info btn-md' href='".base_url()."index.php/welcome/editvendor/".$row->VendorId."' > Edit </a>";
```